# windows 10 Newtonsoft.json deserialize

Tags: windows-10

I am trying to convert my Windows Phone 8.1 project to
Windows10 universal project.

I have the problem with Newtonsoft.Json 7.0.1.
So I uninstalled it and installed Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.8,
which is the same as my Windows phone 8.1 project.

All going well until I try to Deserialize a dynamic JSon object
(This dynamic JSon object has different name and value for each
element every time when I try to access it) 
When I try to use JSonObject.children() function to get the child
element of the JSon Object. (this function works for Windows Phone 8.1)
The program throw ex 'System.InvalidOperationException' in mscorlib.ni.dll.

Comment: Please add some code.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Newtonsoft.json, my solution was to check out / download code from https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json or search for JSON.NET on Github then add a Windows 10 Class Library project and add all the classes from the Github project and then build, might need to resolve some minor things but no code changes were required, and got it to work.